# ¿Se puede utilizar Java, google drive y Access para hacer una aplicación?

Tags: java, base-de-datos

Mi idea es hacer una aplicación que conecte con una bd de **access 2010** (ya hice algunas previamente) pero quiero que la aplicación corra en diferentes pc (2 o 3)

¿sería muy mala idea conectar con una bd en la **nube**?

¿Que otros métodos tengo para tener **concurrencia** en la bd desde diferentes lugares?

PD: Todavía no cursé bases de datos en la universidad, sé hacer consultas y demás, pero nunca hice algo con una bd en un servidor.

Answer (score 1):

No tengo permisos para añadir comentarios pero las bases de datos de Access tienen como limitación, entre otras cosas, que sólo tienen capacidad para 2 Gb. Y lo más importante, que para usarlo en un entorno de red no es lo más adecuado.

Si vas a trabajar sirviendo datos a varios clientes (clientes-servidor) lo mejor es SQL server (access no deja de ser una demo de sql server). O MySQL que puede trabajar con java también. Alternativas hay muchas.

Lo de google drive no termino de comprender para qué lo quieres enganchar con access.

Comment: Por que no tengo idea como se mete en un servidor una bd MySQL jaja

Comment: SQL Server o MySQL ya son servidores que base de datos.

Comment: MySQL use pero en local host, pero no se como usarlo por ejemplo en un dominio de internet, simplemente reservo un dominio gratuito y utilizo las direcciones?

Comment: @David lo que quiere hacer MrHall es usar Google Drive para poder "compartir" la BD y que la aplicación pueda accederla "localmente".
Access no es una base de datos "demo" como mencionas. Es una BD que tiene otro fin (es como sqlite).

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que usar un servidor de bd relacional ya que es este quin te va a solucionar los problemas de concurrencia.

Lo que planteas, de meter una BD como access en la nube, es mala idea, porque en algún momento, vas a tener desactualizaciónes producto de que dos clientes actualizaron la BD y probablemente GoogleDrive no va a tener como manejar esa mezcla.

¿Pensaste en hacer una aplicación web? Ahí solucionas en parte el problema de la BD y que varios usuario accedan a tu sistema.

En general, usa un servidor de BD hoy por hoy, es bastante sencillo. La misma lógica que usas en Access la tienes que aplicar en los otros productos: tablas, relaciones y las consultas que quieras armar. Lo que va a cambiar va a ser la forma en que te conectas: pasas de conectarte a un archivo (Access) a un servidor (Mysql, postgres o SqlServer).

Comment: Genial! Muchas gracias, tenes alguno para recomendarme?

Comment: @MrHall en general recomiendo usar lo que usen tus cercanos. Mysql es muy popular pero Postgres no se queda atrás. Este último tiene una comunidad en español muy buena.

Comment: Genial te agradezco! Nunca desarrolle nada en la web, estoy en la universidad y solo se java y algo de python. En este momento estoy desarrollando un chat para ver bien el tema de sockets, Threads y algo de patrones de diseño.